# Renaming file based on filename of another file type

Tags: windows, cmd

Am wanting to use the below code (taken from another topic) at dos command prompt, using batch file, to rename .mkv file using the filename from .txt file. However, if there is a space in the .txt filename the renamed file omits all characters after, and including, the space. E.g. 'movie.txt' works fine but 'the movie.txt' doesn't; they produce the files 'movie.mkv' and 'the.mkv', respectively.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: This assumes there is only one mkv file in the folder
for /F %%A in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
set basename=%%~nA
ren *.mkv !basename!.mkv
)
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: Use double quotes: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested here's a solution I found:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: This assumes there is only one mkv file in the folder
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
set basename="%%~nA"
ren *.mkv !basename!.mkv
)
```

Regards,
Richard